# MongoDB geoWithin missing results

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas

Querying a very simple dataset, only returns 3/4 results every single time.

I can never get ***Vladivostok*** to show.

Query

```
db.locations.find({"location": {"$geoWithin": {"$center" : [[43.1198, 131.8869], 4000]} } })
```

Data

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d826a4d1efa91047ca21941"), 
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Point", 
        "coordinates" : [
            59.9138, 
            10.7522
        ]
    }, 
    "name" : "Oslo"
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d826b1b258557047c43d397"), 
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Point", 
        "coordinates" : [
            59.9938, 
            10.7522
        ]
    }, 
    "name" : "North of Oslo"
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d826b33258557047c43d398"), 
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Point", 
        "coordinates" : [
            43.1198, 
            131.8869
        ]
    }, 
    "name" : "Vladivostok"
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d826b65258557047c43d399"), 
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Point", 
        "coordinates" : [
            -22.9068, 
            -43.1729
        ]
    }, 
    "name" : "Rio"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you use longitude and latitude, specify coordinates in order of
>   longitude, latitude.

from [`$geoWithin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/)

Your values are always in normal [latitude, longitude] order, but for MongoDB, [it is in reverse](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/#geojson-objects), which is really really confusing tbh

If you revert the order for all geo locations in your example, you will get all four points in your result.

Test it on [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XcR8nUp4PDP)

Comment: I agree that is really bad since almost everywhere else on the internet always uses lat, long :-/

Answer (score 1):

Mongodb expects you to store as [lng, lat].

Longitude angles can range up to +180 degrees (180 degrees east), and down to -180 degrees (180 degrees west).
Latitude angles can range up to +90 degrees (or 90 degrees north), and down to -90 degrees (or 90 degrees south).

```
    { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d826b33258557047c43d398"), 
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Point", 
        "coordinates" : [
            43.1198, 
            131.8869
        ]
    }, 
    "name" : "Vladivostok"
}
```

So please check the coordinates. {131.8869, 43.1198}